# click event for facebook in android

Tags: android, cordova

Hi in my android phonegap app I have used create chooser to get all share application from the mobile.Its working fine,but i need to call separate intent for facebook.So i need click event for facebook from the dialog.

Here is my code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject );  
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"www.google.com");

    this.ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share"));
```

Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  try {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"e-mail address"};
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "E-mail subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "E-mail text");
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); // This is incorrect MIME, but Gmail is one of the only apps that responds to it - this might need to be replaced with text/plain for Facebook
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") ||
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) best = info;
                if (best != null)
                    emailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
                startActivity(emailIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

You may also try uaual way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The status update text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Dialog title text"));
```

Comment: @ricintech..Thanks for your reply.your code i moving directly to the email.But i need to get the dialog with all share app.from there i need to click email.Please guide me.

Comment: Ok you want to display a dilogue... having all app names as item.

Comment: ya,if i use createchooser it automatically opens the dialog with app names as item and it itself is sharing.But i need to use separate click event for facebook in my own.Please guide me..

Comment: Use this link: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/